# TwitterJS and Twitter 1.1 API

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

Will TwitterJS no longer work after May 7th, when the Twitter 1.0 API goes away?

https://code.google.com/p/twitterjs/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this more I'm able to answer my own question: it won't.

The TwitterJS.js API uses 1.0 and v1 methods:

```
  protocol = document.location.protocol.substr(0, 4) === 'http' ? document.location.protocol : 'http:',
  URLS = {
    search: protocol + '//search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%search%&page=%page|1%&rpp=%limit|100%&since_id=%since|remove%&result_type=recent&include_entities=true', // TODO allow user to change result_type
    timeline: protocol + '//api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=%user%&count=%limit|200%&page=%page|1%&since_id=%since|remove%include_rts=%rts|false%&include_entities=true',
    list: protocol + '//api.twitter.com/1/%user%/lists/%list%/statuses.json?page=%page|1%&per_page=%limit|200%&since_id=%since|remove%&include_entities=true&include_rts=%rts|false%',
    favs: protocol + '//api.twitter.com/1/favorites/%user%.json?include_entities=true&skip_status=true&page=%page|1%&since_id=%since|remove%',
    retweets: protocol + '//api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweeted_by_user.json?screen_name=%user%&include_entities=true&count=%limit|200%&since_id=%since|remove%&page=%page|1%'
  },
```